# Where is the .ddl method defined in Slick's Scaladoc

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I have figured out for creating a Postgres table, I need to have this import line 
`import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._`

However, when I go an look at the [Scaladoc](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#scala.slick.driver.JdbcProfile$SimpleQL) for SimpleQL, I cannot find a method for `ddl`, am I looking in the wrong place? This is really an exercise for me navigating Scaladocs. I can see that `TableQuery` is aliased, but I do not see any extra methods added to it.

TLDR: Where is the `ddl` method defined at in Slick 2.1.0's scala docs?

Comment: Glad to discover that I am not the only desperate person about that.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of method ***ddl*** is included in the description of classes [TableQueryExtensionMethods](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.profile.RelationalProfile$TableQueryExtensionMethods) and [Sequence](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#scala.slick.profile.RelationalSequenceComponent$Sequence). It can be found, for example, via Scaladoc's [index](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#index.index-d).

**Why does that make sense?**

Consider the following code which got myself confused for some time:

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
// [..]
val dict = TableQuery[Dict]
// [..]
// Create the dictionary table and insert some data
dict.ddl.create
```

First, note that the import in given example is very similar to the one in the question. I just use a different database.

Method ***ddl*** is applied to a value of type `TableQuery[Dict]` although class [TableQuery](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/#scala.slick.lifted.TableQuery) obviously does not contain this method.

Instead, it was shown that class [TableQueryExtensionMethods](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.profile.RelationalProfile$TableQueryExtensionMethods) contains this method.

The [implementation](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/2.1.0/src/main/scala/scala/slick/profile/RelationalProfile.scala) of class ***TableQueryExtensionMethods*** shows that Slick's developers make use of an **implicit Conversion** from ***TableQuery*** to ***TableQueryExtensionMethods***:

```
 implicit def tableQueryToTableQueryExtensionMethods [T <: Table[_], U](q: Query[T, U, Seq] with TableQuery[T]) 
    = new TableQueryExtensionMethods[T, U](q)
```

This allows the execution of line

```
dict.ddl.create
```

From the example above.